# Getting the first row from database refreshes the page continuously

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the first row from phpmyadmin. After trying to do it different ways, I thought I would ask. Right now, the problem is that it is refreshing the browser continuously.

i've tried to add a die, but I'm not very good at mysqli/php

```
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM stellingen WHERE REGIOID=1;";
    $records2 =  mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records2);

    while ($stellingen = mysqli_data_seek($records2, 0)){
        echo "<p>".$stellingen['Stelling']."</p>";
    }
```

I expect the php to fetch the first data. In the context of a loop where the next data will nneed to come later in the page.

some more code

```
<div class="stellingen">
    <div class="stelling-wrapper" id="btn1">
        <img src="images/button.svg" alt="Show more..." class="btn" id="bton">
        <p type="button" class="stelling">
<?php
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM stellingen WHERE REGIOID=1;";
    $records2 =  mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records2);

    while ($stellingen = mysqli_data_seek($records2, 0)){
        echo "<p>".$stellingen['Stelling']."</p>";
    }

    /*
    if ($recordscheck2 > 0){
        while ($stellingen = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records2)){
            echo "<p>".$stellingen['Stelling']."</p>";
        }
    }*/
?>
</div>
<div id="p1">
    <table id="tabel" border=1px class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>

<?php
$sql1="SELECT * FROM stelling WHERE stelling_iD=1;";
$records1 =  mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
$recordscheck = mysqli_num_rows($records1);

if ($recordscheck > 0){
    while ($stelling = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records1)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$stelling['Title']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$stelling['Source']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$stelling['Wheight']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$stelling['Timer']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not your full code. There is nothing here that would refresh the page.

Comment: I think he means, it fetches all rows and displays them. When he wants `ORDER BY \`id\` ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: When I take this snippet away, it works fine, it only has html after and before

Comment: Your question with the limited code, is unclear.

Comment: No, it reloads, till the browser says oups

Comment: I added some more code

Comment: You should read the documentation on `mysqli_data_seek`, it's not suppose to be in a `while()` loop. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so your using `mysqli_data_seek()` in a `while()` loop, which is wrong...

```
<?php

if($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM stellingen WHERE REGIOID=1;")) {

    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo "<p>{$row["Stelling"]}</p>";

}

?>
```

Should work for you.

[Edit] I corrected my variable names.

Comment: these are the errors i now get Notice: Undefined variable: records2 ; Warning: mysqli_data_seek() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Comment: i don't think mysqli data seek holds no purpose here as it starts in the first row anyway. just invoke fetch assoc once outside the loop and you'll get the first row in.

Comment: @Ghost yea, it would make more sense to just specify `ORDER` and `LIMIT` in the query, if it's the latest entry he wants.